# Swift view inside scroll view increases width at pull down to refresh

Tags: xcode, swift, uiscrollview, width, pull-to-refresh

I come here with a problem with a scroll view.
I have this scroll view in which I add as subviews a refresh control and after that a custom view (with many elements in it), loaded from a `xib`. All good at this point, everything loads and looks ok.

The problem comes when I pull down to refresh the scroll view: the width of the custom view increases(from 375.0 to 592.0 - I do not know why this number...), while the scroll view maintains its width (375.0).

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?
I mention that I use `autolayout` and that I have constraints in place.

At refresh I remove all subview from the scroll view:

```
let subViews = self.scrollViewContent.subviews
        for subview in subViews{
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
```

Before I recreate the content view to add again to the scroll view.

What is going wrong here? What could I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a constraint in the storyboard or programmatically that sets the custom view's width to always match the width of the scrollView. You can try this in the refresh control:

```
customView.frame = CGRect(x: whateverX, y: whateverY, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: customView.frame.height)
```

Comment: It did not work with only storyboard constraints, which I already had. But with the programmatic ones it's ok.